# expected identifier in #define statement

Tags: c++, linux, macros, shared-libraries

[See my own answer below.]

I have this code in a header file of my project:

```
#ifdef _LINUX
    #ifdef BUILD_ext
        #define EXP_IMP_GLOBAL extern
    #else
        #define EXP_IMP_GLOBAL
    #endif
#else
```

G++ tells me the following when BUILD_ext is defined:

```
error: expected identifier before ‘extern’
         #define EXP_IMP_GLOBAL extern
                                ^
note: in expansion of macro ‘EXP_IMP_GLOBAL’
    class EXP_IMP_GLOBAL Classname
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I don't really know what to make of this error since the error doesn't appear when BUILD_ext is not defined and I also don't see, why there would be no identifier.

Comment: Well, `class extern Classname` is not valid C++.

Comment: You can't specify `extern` for a class. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem here was, that I completely misunderstood what `extern` did. What I wanted, was to control if certain classes of my library where visible from the outside or not and also basically to partly imitate the behavior of `__declspec (dllexport)/__declspec (dllimport)`

To get what I needed, I had to change the line

```
#define EXP_IMP_GLOBAL extern
```

to

```
#define EXP_IMP_GLOBAL extern __attribute__((visibility("default")))
```

and use the compiler flag `-fvisibility=hidden`

Answer (score 3):

> I don't really know what to make of this error since the error doesn't
>   appear when BUILD_ext is not defined and I also don't see, why there
>   would be no identifier.

When both `_LINUX` and `BUILD_ext` are defined, `EXP_IMP_GLOBAL` is expanded into `extern`. So you have:

```
class extern Classname
```

in your code.

According to this [page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration):

> The extern specifier is only allowed in the declarations of variables
>   and functions (except class members or function parameters).

So you cannot use `extern` specifier with class declaration/definition and compiler complains.

I guess you might simply remove `EXP_IMP_GLOBAL` to get rid of the error because `EXP_IMP_GLOBAL` does not make sense when it is used like now.

Answer (score -3):

Not sure what you are trying to do but **extern** is C++ keyword and you cannot use it that way. Also, any character sequence must be put between quotes:

```
#define EXP_IMP_GLOBAL "extern"
```

Comment: This is false. There is no such restriction on using keywords in macros, nor requirements like using quotes. If this define was substituted, you'd end up with eg. `class "extern" Classname`, which makes even less sense than the original.

Comment: Compile this: `#define EXT test

#include <iostream>

int main() {
 std::cout << EXT << std::endl;
 return 0;
}
`

Comment: And it won't work, as `test` isn't defined. In that situation, using `#define EXT "test"` makes sense, but in a situation like this where the macro is being substituted for a keyword, it makes no sense - he's not wanting a string out of it, he's wanting a language feature.

Comment: @VladimirKanazir Compile this: `#define EXT test #include <iostream> int main() { int test = 0; std::cout << EXT << std::endl; return 0; }`

Comment: Well, we don't know what OP is trying to do exactly, right?